# Publishing on appExchange

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, partner-portal, lma

Here is what i have done so far..I have created a ISV/APO from the link http://www.salesforce.com/partners. Then i have Requested for Parter dev org. Creted my managed package in Parter dev org. Now i want to publish to appExchange(as a free app).
1) I have read from ISVforce guide that i need to install LMA to any org to track installed app. When i created the case for same then i got the status as case-Closed..with 
Note: The LMA is only available for partners who have a fully executed contract with their ISV Account Executive.
What does this mean?
How to proceed further?
how can i Complete contract with ISV Account Executive?
2)How to list my managed package on appExchange which is in my Partner Dev Org.

This is my first attempt to publish app on appExchange. I have been reading the docs relating to it. But not able to get Straight forward steps for publishing.

Please do help to make my journey easier.

Very much Thanks for helping ..in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Publish Your First App with AppExchange Checkout](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Publish_Your_First_App_with_AppExchange_Checkout). It lists all the steps necessary to publish an app to the app exchange, including going through the required security review. There are lots of links from that page which provide additional details for anything you don't understand or steps you haven't completed. For a more comprehensive document, see the [AppExchange Publishing Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.appExchangePublishGuide.meta/appExchangePublishGuide/appexchange_overview.htm).

You might also find some of the webinar videos found at [APP Academy: Plan (Getting Started)](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/appvendors/APP_Academy_Plan) helpful to you in beginning your journey.